# Referenced assemblies in C# what .NET version do they use?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am upgrading a solution to .NET 4 and use third party referenced assemblies.  These assemblies were compiled using .NET 2.0 and some with 3.5.  When I run the upgraded apps in .NET 4, what version of .NET will the third party assemblies run in?  Will it be still using .NET 2.0 or 3.5 or will they run in 4.0?  IF they do run in a higher version of .NET, does that cause any issues with them being compiled in an earlier version?  The apps are Windows Forms and ASP.NET if that makes a difference.

Comment: There are a lot of questions already addressing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836704/running-net-3-5-built-mixed-mode-assemblies-in-net-4-using-app-config-requires, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179028/mixed-mode-assembly-in-net-4, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050781/net-3-5-dlls-in-a-net-4-0-application-any-issues

Answer (score 0):

Your referenced assemblies will be loaded in .NET 4.0 framework runtime, since your main solution will be using it. There are few exceptions though, if the third party assemblies are strictly using old version of .net code and if that code/methods are obsolete you may get warning/errors.

Answer (score 0):

What assemblies are you actually talking about? Most of assemblies such as DB connectors work pretty well with .NET 4.0 even compiled with earlier versions.You just have to make some changes in the app.config file in most cases.. Can't say much without knowing about the exact class library ur talking about.